# Using Java reflection to modify nesting class's fields from inner class

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, inner-classes, nested-class

I'm experiencing odd behavior while debugging my Java reflection homework in Eclipse.
I have 2 classes defined:

```
public class OuterClass{
    protected Person person;

    public void aPerson(Integer age) {
        person = new Person(age);
    }
}

public class OuterDerivedClass extends OuterClass {

    public class InnerClass extends OuterClass {

        public void aPerson(Integer age) {
            person = new Person(age);
        }
    }
}
```

At some point in my program, I instantiated an InnerClass instance like so (using reflection as my program is supposed to work on *any* class. Nested classes could be either static/non-static and public/private/protected):

```
Class<?> outer_class = outer_instance.getClass();
Constructor<?> ctor = inner_class.getDeclaredConstructor(outer_class);
Object inner_instance = ctor.newInstance(outer_instance);
```

Later on I invoked the OuterDerivedClass$InnerClass.aPerson method:

```
method.invoke(inner_instance, parameter);
```

For now, it seemed like all went OK: The inner_instance was created successfully, the correct aPerson method (the one in InnerClass) was invoked. BUT, later on my program, as I tried to access the person field from outer_instance, I figured out it was still NULL (though it was created in aPerson method).
While debugging in Eclipse, I found out this:

[image]

(PersonStoryDerivedTest == OuterDerivedClass in my question).

The id of this$0 is the same as the one I sent to the constructor (outer_instance). I couldn't figure out what is the second person field (the one that apparently was created by invoking aPerson). Isn't this field supposed to exist only in the nesting class? My intention was that the invocation of OuterDerivedClass$InnerClass.aPerson would change the person field in outer_instance (I thought this is the reason why it was sent to the Constructor in the first place).

Can someone please clarify these issues? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand this right, your question is about why `person = new Person(age)` sets `this.person` and not `OuterDerivedClass.this.person`? And all the reflection stuff is irrelevant (the same thing happens if you do it without reflection)?

Comment: To get getter answers faster consider [edit]ing your question to include [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). As your question is currently written it has few confusing parts like what is `testInstance` and why was it used in `method.invoke(testInstance, parameter);` instead of `inner_instance`. Make your example short, but fully compilable.

Comment: @immibis that is the main question. I didn't try doing it without reflection as I was having trouble accessing the concrete classes (they are passed as Class objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I couldn't figure out what is the second person field

Well, since

```
public class InnerClass extends OuterClass {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

your `InnerClass` also inherits its own `person` field which is set by

```
public void aPerson(Integer age) {
    person = new Person(age);
}
```

because `person` refers to `this.person` and `this` inside this method represents instance of class where method was implemented (in InnerClass).

If you want your method to initialize `OuterClass#person` field you need to refer to it via  `OuterDerivedClass.this.person`, but this will leave uninitialized `person` field of `InnerClass`.

Other (simpler) option is not extending `OuterClass` from `InnerClass`:

```
public class InnerClass{
```

Comment: Wow. Totally missed that part even though (or probably because) I was staring at the code for like 5 hours. thanks!